# Possibility to check if there's a valid connection available for a given IP and a Port in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a bit of a tricky issue to solve. Using my C# application I'm establishing a TCP client connection to a device connected via Ethernet. User can give a IP and a Port to the provided fields and can connect to the device just by pressing a button. I have a try/catch block for exception handling if the user enters a wrong IP/Port number.

```
    //Constructor
    public DepotETHInterface(string ip, int port)
    {
        ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        connectionActive = false;
    }


    public void Connect()
    {
        try
        {

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint,new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
            connectionActive = true;       
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte geben Sie eine gültige IP und einen Port an", "Keine Verbindung vorhanden", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

But for some reason it takes ages to display the MessageBox in case it runs into the catch block. Is there a better work around for this?

Comment: If an invalid IP is entered, it'll time out I'd imagine. What's the timeout period?

Comment: @DiskJunky lol until you say I never set a timeout period. Maybe this is the solution. Thanks for the hint :) I'm a noob xD

Comment: You can use PING to test if a device is on Ethernet.  The response to the PING contains the MAC (Manufacture, Model, Serial Number) of device so you know the IP is for the correct device.

Comment: To see how to PING in code, google "ICMP Echo request"

Comment: @jdweng this assume that ICMP is allowed on the target IPs

Comment: Never seen PC where ICMP was disabled.  It is a good tool for everybody to use, not just Admins.  Besides Admins can't stop applications in c# from using ICMP.  Just disable the cmd version of Ping.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Ping.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx(v=vs.110).aspx) function

```
Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(address);
```

this method will return a [PingReply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains the information of the packet you sent.